# How to make ligatures work for "Fragment Mono" font?

Tags: fonts

I use Emacs with [Tuareg](https://github.com/ocaml/tuareg) for writing code in OCaml.
Also, I write code in documents out of Emacs (not for compilation) and found that some fixed-pitch fonts are pretty good in visualization for some operators. The following image shows how Fragment Mono font renders character pairs to single characters with two symbols width.

[image]

I have added Fragment Mono as default to my init file, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Fragment Mono")
```

The font was applied without the merging feature. Is it possible to do something to fix this problem?

Comment: "ligatures" would be a good search term here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs has support for this kind of "merging", but calls it "composition". You need to explicitly configure it for this kind of situation.

The following code somewhere in your init file should do the trick for the compositions you mentioned.

```
(let ((al '((?- . "->")
            (?< . "<[=-]")
            (?! . "!=")
            (?> . ">=")
            (?= . "==")
            (?| . "|>"))))
  (dolist (elt al)
    (aset composition-function-table
      (car elt)
      `([,(cdr elt) 0 compose-gstring-for-graphic]))))
```

Comment: It's so easy, and it works. My investigation of ligatures got me much more complicated solutions.